# C# WinForms not accepting connection string user details

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a connection string in App.config like so:

```
<add name="connectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;User ID=domain\username;Password=12345;Connection Timeout=300"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I then call the string in code behind like so:

```
string conSTR = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlDataReader reader;
                using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conSTR))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, sqlConn))
                {
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                     .... stuff happens here
                    }
                }
```

MY local account does not have access to the server but the service account passed into the connection string does.

The error I get is:

```
Cannot open database "DB" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'domain\MyUserName'.
```

For some reason it is completely ignoring the user name/password in the connection string and tries to connect using my account.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have integrated security = true in your connection string, remove that.

Comment: Sometimes the simple things... But now I am getting the service account `Login failed for user 'domain\\account'."` even though the password is correct. Is it expecting a SQL login and not Windows Authentication?

Comment: Yes you can use either integrated security as the current windows user or SQL login.  If you want to login using an alternative domain account you'll have to use impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

That because you're specifying `Integrated Security=True;`. This overrules any other authentication settings, remove it and it will use the username and password supplied.